# Endlocal & "set var" not working as expected in "for" loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, local-variables

I'm doing a job, copying files from one location to another location using BATCH file. I split my statements into three parts, one program driver, one for generating file list under each sub-directory, and one for checking file name & doing actual copy stuff.

1.PROGRAM DRIVER

```
IF EXIST TEMP.TXT DEL TEMP.TXT
CD>TEMP.TXT
set /p ROOT=<TEMP.TXT

rem PARA is the date to copy
SET PARA=2013-08-06
ECHO %PARA%
CD %ROOT%\%PARA%
FOR /R %%A IN (.) DO (    ::COPY SUB-LOGIC FILE TO EACH SUB-DIRECTORY
    ECHO NOW IN %%A
    CD %%A
    XCOPY "%ROOT%\WORK.BAT" . /K /Y
    XCOPY "%ROOT%\CORE.BAT" . /K /Y
    ECHO LOOP OUT.
)

CD %ROOT%\%PARA%
FOR /R %%A IN (.) DO (
    ECHO NOW IN %%A
    CD %%A
    CALL WORK.BAT        ::GENERATING FILE LIST
    ECHO LOOP OUT.
)

CD %ROOT%\%PARA%
FOR /R %%A IN (.) DO (
    ECHO NOW IN %%A
    CD %%A
    CALL CORE.BAT        ::DOING COPY STUFF
    ECHO LOOP OUT.
)

PAUSE
```

2.WORK.BAT

```
IF EXIST FILE.TXT DEL FILE.TXT
FOR %%B IN (*.wav) DO ECHO %%~nxB>>FILE.TXT
```

3.COPYING STUFF

```
FOR %%F IN ("%CD%") DO SET CURDIR=%%~nxF
IF NOT EXIST FILE.TXT GOTO END
SET CCC="FALSE"  ::IF NO CCC DECLARED HERE,BELOW FOR LOOP WILL BE SKIPPED
PAUSE
FOR /F %%C IN (FILE.TXT) DO (
    SETLOCAL
    SET RES="FALSE"
    IF "%%C" GEQ "CH201_00000000_000.WAV" SET RES="TRUE"
    IF "%%C" LEQ "CH300_FFFFFFFF_FFF.WAV" (
         SET RES="TRUE"
    ) ELSE ( SET RES="FALSE")
    ENDLOCAL& SET CCC=%RES%    *::VAR CCC NOT UPDATED*
    PAUSE
    IF %CCC% EQU "TRUE" (
        IF NOT EXIST D:\PHILIPS\%PARA%\%PARA%\%CURDIR% MD D:\PHILIPS\%PARA%\%PARA%\%CURDIR%
        XCOPY "%ROOT%\%PARA%\%CURDIR%\%%C" D:\PHILIPS\%PARA%\%PARA%\%CURDIR% /K /Y
    )
)
:END
ECHO LOOP OUT
```

My question is, why my "ENDLOCAL & SET" statement not working, i.e., NULL each time, as pictures show. How can I change my statements to make it work as expected?

[image: First image]

[image: Second image]

---

I changed part 3 to

```
FOR %%F IN ("%CD%") DO SET CURDIR=%%~nxF
IF NOT EXIST FILE.TXT GOTO END
SET "RES="
PAUSE
FOR /F %%C IN (FILE.TXT) DO (
    SET "RES="
    IF "%%C" GEQ "CH201_00000000_000.WAV" SET "RES=Y"
    IF "%%C" LEQ "CH300_FFFFFFFF_FFF.WAV" (
        SET "RES=Y"
    ) ELSE ( SET "RES=" )
    PAUSE
    IF DEFINED RES (
            IF NOT EXIST D:\PHILIPS\%PARA%\%PARA%\%CURDIR% MD D:\PHILIPS\%PARA%\%PARA%\%CURDIR%
            XCOPY "%ROOT%\%PARA%\%CURDIR%\%%C" D:\PHILIPS\%PARA%\%PARA%\%CURDIR% /K /Y
    )
)
```

It seems that RES always defined, even FILENAME is in specified ranges. In this case, it copied wrong files.

[image: New runtime result]

Comment: Please don't link to external sites - there is too high a probability that the link will become invalid. There's a magic 'graphic' button available over the edit box to include graphics by uploading them to SO.

Comment: when I post this thread, SO notices me that I need at least 10 reputation to upload images. So I take an intermediate way. Thanks, Magoo

Comment: Yeah -puts the brakes on spammers. Pain for legitimate users. I've no objection to blue-pencilling legitimate posts thogh. HTH.

Comment: Hi Magoo, it's inconvenient to place code in comments. I posted another answer. Please help to improve. Thanks, bro

Comment: I've reduced the title volume too. Caps are discouraged. And added the `cmd` tag as *NIXers use batchfiles too. BTW: You can redirect `cmd` output to a file by using *yourbatchname* >*afilename* - that should make it easier to post runtime reports - no need for images.

Comment: Great. Mission accomplished. Last step is to click the tick to allow others to know the problem's been solved. This also allots points, including rep points to you to start you on your way to 10 / 50 and permission to comment/add graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in (3)

```
FOR /F %%C IN (FILE.TXT) DO (
    SETLOCAL
    SET RES="FALSE"
    IF "%%C" GEQ "CH201_00000000_000.WAV" SET RES="TRUE"
    IF "%%C" LEQ "CH300_FFFFFFFF_FFF.WAV" (
         SET RES="TRUE"
    ) ELSE ( SET RES="FALSE")
    ENDLOCAL& SET CCC=%RES%    *::VAR CCC NOT UPDATED*
    PAUSE
    IF %CCC% EQU "TRUE" (
        IF NOT EXIST D:\PHILIPS\%PARA%\%PARA%\%CURDIR% MD D:\PHILIPS\%PARA%\%PARA%\%CURDIR%
        XCOPY "%ROOT%\%PARA%\%CURDIR%\%%C" D:\PHILIPS\%PARA%\%PARA%\%CURDIR% /K /Y
    )
)
```

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Note therefore the use of `CALL ECHO %%var%%` which displays the changed value of `var`. `CALL ECHO %%errorlevel%%` displays, but sadly then RESETS errorlevel.

Where flags are involved, the situation changes again. `set "flag="` will ensure a flag is cleared. `set "flag=somethingelse"` will ensure it is set (the value is not relevant.) Using `if defined flag (doiftrue) else (doiffalse)` works on the **run-time** (current) status of `flag` - not the **parse-time** value.

Hence, I suggest you change your processing, setting `ccc` to either *nothing* with a `set "ccc="` statement or something with a `set "ccc=y"` and you can then test for true/false using `if [not] defined ccc`

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned. `set /a` can safely be used "quoteless".

---

(on revised code)

Your tests are incorrect.

`res` will **not** be set to `Y`  with value `CH145...` against `CH201...`
But it **will** be set to `Y` in the `LEQ` test as `CH145...` **is** lestt than or equal to `CH300...`

You may either cascade the setting:

```
if "%%C" GEQ "CH201..." IF "%%C" LEQ "CH300..." set "res=Y"
```

or gate the test

```
IF "%%C" GEQ "CH201_00000000_000.WAV" SET "RES=Y"
if defined res IF "%%C" GTR "CH300_FFFFFFFF_FFF.WAV" SET "RES="
```

Comment: IN my origrinal code, I used cascaded IF for condition tests. But I changed to multiple statements for dedugging. Now it works as expected. Thanks, Magoo :)